# UIActivityViewControllerを使うと発生するメモリリークの解消方法を教えてください

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

swiftでアプリを開発しています。
UIActivityViewControllerを使ってアクティビティダイアログを表示した際にメモリリークしています。
リークを解消させる方法の見当がつかず困っています。解決方法についてご教示ください。
コードは最後に載せておきます。(一部書き換えています。)

処理内容は、出力したCSVファイルをアクティビティダイアログに表示されたAirDropまたはメーラーで送信する、というものです。
instrumentsで確認した際のssを添付します。iphone(ios8.4)と、ipadmini(ios9.3.4)で実行しました。それぞれダイアログを表示させる画面へ遷移し5回ダイアログを開閉しました。

[image: iphoneで実行]

↑iphoneでは「_UIAlertControllerCommmonInit」でNSMutableArrayがリークしているようです。このssでは2つのリークですが、開閉の回数分リークしている時もあります。

↓ipadのssはスタックトレースの内容が異なる3枚を載せておきます。(他のは、IsImage、IsContactの部分のみがIsPDFのような感じで異なっています。)
ipadでは「CSStringCopyCFString」でNSCFStringがドカドカとリークしています。さらに開閉する毎にヒープが高くなっている(閉じても何か残っている？)点も気になります。こちらについても原因や回避策があればお教えください。よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: ipadminiで実行(1/3)]

[image: ipadminiで実行(2/3)]

[image: ipadminiで実行(3/3)]

```
/// ボタン押下時処理(CSVファイル作成＋転送)
func tapButton() {

    //CSVファイルを出力
    let strFullPath: String = outputCSVFile("sample.csv")
    print("csvpath:" + strFullPath)

    //(出力成功)アクティビティダイアログ表示
    if strFullPath != "" {
        _ad = MyAd() //広告をロード

        let body: String = NSLocalizedString("MSG_SEND", comment: "body文言")
        let file = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: strFullPath)
        let handler: (Bool -> Void) = { [unowned self] (completed) in
            if completed == true {
                self._ad?.show(self)
                print("CSV送信完了！")
            }
        }
        dispDialog(self, items: [body, file], btn: btnAction, arrow: .Up, handler: handler)

    //(出力失敗)エラーメッセージ表示
    } else {
        dispErrMsg(self, strMsg: NSLocalizedString("MSG_FILE_ERR", comment: "エラー発生"))

    }
}

/// アクティビティダイアログを表示
class func dispDialog(vc: UIViewController, items: [AnyObject], btn: UIBarButtonItem, arrow: UIPopoverArrowDirection = .Unknown, handler: (Bool -> Void)! = nil) {
    let dialog = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)

    //使用しないアクティビティタイプ
    let excluded = [
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeMessage,
    ]
    dialog.excludedActivityTypes = excluded

    //完了後の処理をセット
    if handler != nil {
        dialog.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: String?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            print("activityType: \(activityType)")
            handler(completed)
            return
        }
    }

    //For iPad And Univarsal Device
    if let popCtrl = dialog.popoverPresentationController {
        popCtrl.sourceView = vc.view
        popCtrl.permittedArrowDirections = arrow
        popCtrl.barButtonItem = btn
    }

    vc.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

画像を追加しました。
[image: iphone autoreleasepool追加]

Comment: 試してないので情報共有程度になるのですが、[本家SOのこの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988315)は参考になりませんか？

Answer (score 1):

Objective-Cでは、`@autoreleasepool`でメモリリークが起きるブロックを括ることでリークを減少させるので、

```
autoreleasepool {
    dispDialog(self, items: [body, file], btn: btnAction, arrow: .Up, handler: handler)
}
```

と、`displayDialog`関数を`autoreleasepool`で括ってみてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: 早速iphone,ipadで試してみましたが、現象は変わらずでした＞＜

Comment: リークが解放されるタイミングはメソッドを抜けた時点ですが、そこまでトレースしてみましたか？

Comment: はい。メソッドも抜けて試しに当該ビューコントローラーも閉じるところまでやってみました。質問文に画像を追加しました。

Comment: お役に立てず申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: いえいえ、autoreleasepoolというものを知りませんでしたので大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました<(_ _)>